# Safari CSS Animation Multiple Translates Not Working

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, mobile-safari

I have the following code that works in all other browsers except Safari:

```
.background {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;

  transform: translateX(-42px) translateY(166px) skew(25deg);
  animation: background-anim 5s 0s step-end 2;
}

@keyframes background-anim {
  0%, 49%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0) skew(25deg);
  }

  50%, 99% {
    transform: translateX(-42px) translateY(166px) skew(25deg);
  }
}
```

The `translateY()` works but the `translateX()` does not during the animation. However it works outside of the animation (after it finishes).

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/BBlackwo/pen/KQyXzJ?editors=1100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a `translateX(0)` to the first keyframe:

```
@keyframes background-anim {
  0%, 49%, 100% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) skew(25deg);
  }

  50%, 99% {
    transform: translateX(-42px) translateY(166px) skew(25deg);
  }
}
```

Another way was to use `translate(0,0)` and `translate(-42px, 166px)` instead of splitting out into `X` and `Y`.